# How to create a more complex animation in flutter like the movement of water droplet in a container?

Tags: flutter, simulation, flutter-animation

I was wondering if it is possible to create more complex animations using Flutter SDK, for example, the movement of water droplets over a surface, or other natural objects' movement simulations! If it is possible, can you please guide me to the corresponding resources? Thanks.

Comment: Please look into this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/physics-simulation